# Spark 1.4.0 compute-classpath.sh

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have downloaded the latest spark version 1.4.0 and started using it. 
But I couldn't find the compute-classpath.sh file in bin/ which I am using in previous versions to provide third party libraries to my application.

Can anyone please let me know where I can provide CLASSPATH with my third party libs in 1.4.0?

Thanks 
Lokesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use: spark.driver.extraClassPath property which can be set in spark-defaults.conf file from /conf folder or by setting it to SparkConf class. More info here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html
Search after spark.driver.extraClassPath